# how to show different row in different page from db in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

hello i just like to know how i can show second row from db.
and another page will show 3rd row from db.

How i can ?
This controller for view data from model

```
public function view_main_body() {
$data = array();
$data['main_body_details'] = $this->sa_model->select_main_body();
$data['admin_content'] = $this->load->view('admin/view_page_content', $data, true);
$this->load->view('admin/index', $data);
}
```

here is the model which show data from database

```
public function select_main_body() {
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('tbl_main_body');
$result_query = $this->db->get();
$result = $result_query->row();
return $result;
}
```

here is the welcome controller which show in frontpage

```
public function index()
{ $data=array();
$data['menu_details'] = $this->sa_model->select_menu();
$data['maincontent']=$this->load->view('home_message',$data,true);
$this->load->view('index',$data);
}





<?php echo $main_body_details->main_body; ?>
```

this is code show fast row result but i want to show my second row from db.
another page 3rd row from db

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to look into using the CodeIgniter pagination class, this is well documented on the CodeIgniter site. I would go read that because it will show you how to do what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your question but you can use

```
$this->db->limit(1, $which_row);
```

(you'd set $which_row to whichever database row you want to get.

Basically this says "limit rows returned to 1 and offset by $which_row".

You should also use

```
$this->db->order_by('field_name', 'asc/desc');
```

to ensure you're getting them in a specific order (if that matters)